# Error while installing P4Python on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, perforce, p4python

Configuration:

```
Machine: windows8 64-bit
Pyhton 2.7
Environment variable:
    PATH: %PATH%;C:\Python27
    PYTHONPATH: C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;
```

While installing P4Python 2.7, I got following message:

> There was a problem tying to get the P4Python install path.
>
> Possible reasons are:
>
> 1) Python is not installed.
>
> 2) An unsupported version or architecture of Python is installed.
>
> 3) The folder containing the Python executable is not in the system path.
>
> 4) Another version or architecture of Python is in the system path before the supported version or architecture.
>
> 5) The P4Python install paths are not writable.

I also tried installing P4Python 3.3 and got same message.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/download/guest/robert_cowham/perforce/utils/python/bin/p4python-2014.1.807760.win32-py2.7.exe

The installer from main site only work with *P64-bit Python 3.3*.

I got this answer from perforce forum.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, then had to change to 64 bit P4Python for 2.7 and 64 bit Python 2.7 .

Comment: If you could say more from the reasons, possible reasons, it would be probably highly useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to completely uninstall the python 2.7 and earlier versions of python and reinstall it for 64-bit architecture. After installing goto Start->Python 2.7->IDLE would work fine

Comment: IDLE demanded `python_2.7.2.msi` so i installed it but `idle` didn't opened and installing `P4Python` again gives the same error message

Answer (score 0):

dont do all that i figured where your going wrong dont set the path in that manner there i a simple way to do so
there is a simple procedure to do it go to controlpanel->system and security ->system->advanced system settings->advanced->environment variables then add new path
[add the path and vlues accordingly as shown in img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48gci.png)